# What is the difference between Rf Gain Blocks & IF Gain Blocks?

Tags: amplifier, rf, gain

As advertised on websites of large manufacturers like [**Analog Devices**](http://www.analog.com/en/rfif-components/rfif-amplifiers/adl5531/products/product.html) And [**Texas Instruments**](http://www.ti.com/product/ths9001)

I am aware of the difference between an IF stage and an RF stage, however, I was curious if there was any any other differences. Say I have a 50-500MHz IF gain block, is it OK to either use it in a 200MHz IF stage of a Tx system, or (and this is my question) use it in a 200MHz RF stage of another system?

Comment: How much do you know about RF and IF? It says nothing on your profile so anyone attempting to answer this potentially "ever-so-complicated" subject, would not know where to start.

Comment: If a manufacturer is making a distinction, my guess wold be that it relates to signal (and noise) levels. An "RF" module would be working with lower-level signals (e.g., directly from an antenna) than an "IF" module, which would have had some amplification ahead of it.

Comment: @Andyaka : mmm... Ok I just updated my profile.

Answer (score 1):

RF gain blocks usually operate at 50/70 ohm terminations in their design.

IF gain devices for IF stages usually have 200ohm - 600ohm terminations for saw, crystal, ceramic and mechanical filters.

They can be used interchangeably but you need to upmatch or down match their impedance terminations.

Answer (score 0):

In an rf transmitter, there can be different gain stages in the radio (and/or amplifier) design.  As the signalling makes its way through the radio, it is converted to different frequencies to make it easier to process.  These in-between frequencies are referred to as Intermediate Frequencies.

An rf gain block generally refers to an amplifier for the final transmitting frequency.  An IF gain block works within an intermediate frequency.

Here is the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_frequency) site on IF.

Hope this helps :)